# Wrong package name when using automatically added imports in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have several Maven projects converted into one Eclipse workspace. When I edit the code under Eclipse, I sometimes use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> combination of keys to automatically add imports to the classes from a project in my workspace. But somehow they are added like this:

```
import src.main.java.com.mycompany;
```

while to real package I wanted to import is `com.mycompany`. 
This has to be some configuration in Eclipse to fix this but I'm confused. However, this issue is very annoying.

EDIT:

I've forgotten to mention that Eclipse files were generated using `mvn eclipse:eclipse` command.

Under Eclipse project seems to be configured properly. Its source folders set like this:

- src/test/java
- src/test/resources
- src/main/java
- src/main/resources

And everything under Eclipse works properly except the situation when I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> keys

Comment: As a side note, there is an Eclipse plugin for handling Maven projects named m2eclipse.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The standard source folder for Java projects is

```
./src
```

For imported maven projects, simply remove this folder from the list of source folders at the build path settigs. The correct source folder is

```
./src/main/java
```

Comment: Works great, I had /src/main/java and other path marked as source folders. Only one entry (with the main project folder path) was wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks!! Saved my time.

Comment: thanks , we can do it also from config build path , in source just delete the existing folder and add java folder again.

Comment: This was the underlying problem, but the easiest way for me to fix it was to remove the project from Eclipse (STS), delete all Eclipse related files in the directory and then reimport the Gradle project.

Answer (score 19):

In eclipse;

Remove the existing source folders first.
-right click -> menu -> build path -> remove from build path

then

Right click on the source folder.
build path -> use as source folder.

Seems like your settings are pointing to the parent of the source folder so src is recognized as package by eclipse.

Comment: Thanks. Simple yet powerful !.

Answer (score 4):

It's because eclipse is not aware of the *convention over configuration* filestructure Maven is following. Install the [M2Eclipse](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/) plugin and `File > New > Other > Maven Project` for new projects or for existing ones right click on your imported project on `Package Explorer` > `Maven > Enable Dependency Management`. Once successfully done, on the Package Explorer you would see your project nicely gathered following the Maven conventonal filestructure like  `src/main/java`, `src/main/resources`, `src/test/java` and from then on you'll start seeing your package structure hierarchy like `com.mysite.myproject..`

Comment: I have M2Eclipse installed and all my project have "Enable Dependency Management" turned on.

Comment: as bmargulies and Andreas_D have pointed out try to configure what is source folder and what is not by right clicking > Java Build Path> Source tab

Comment: @Likasz - If you are using M2Eclipse, just doing an Import as Maven Project should set everything up correctly.  If you don't see an M over your project in the package explorer, this is not configured properly.  If this is the case, right click on the project and select Maven->Update Project Configuration.

Comment: This was a good starting point for me.  I ended up using `Update Project` on an existing project that broke due to some git magic that i did through the terminal

Answer (score 3):

First remove it. Then add it back using right click on package->build path->configure build path-> Source->Add Folder and add the entire /src/main/java tree

Answer (score 0):

You've got the wrong source folders in your build path, and it's a wonder that anything works at all.

You can use either the maven-eclipse-plugin or M2Eclipse to automate getting this right, or you can manually fix the build path to call our your actual source folders, not their great-grandparents.

Answer (score 0):

Non of the above worked for me. Finally I just changed the name of the scr folder to scr-java and this removed the package structure with scr as root package.