# Problem in packages in importing in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to import some existing projects into Eclipse.
The structures for their packages is:

```
Project/
        /src
          /java
             /a
              /b
                /c
```

Once imported in the package explorer I see:

```
Project
  src/java
       --a
         --b
            --c
               - AClass.java
```

This is ok, since the classes e.g. AClass.java are defined in package: `a.b.c`
But in one project the structure (once imported) becomes:

```
Project
  src
     --java
        --a
          --b
            --c
              - AClass.java
```

And that causes the error that AClass.java is defined to be in package `a.b.c` but it is actually under `java.a.b.c`
Why is this happening? Why in this specific project java is not ignored as part of package?
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How are you creating the Eclipse projects? It sounds like you just need to put "java" as a root on on the source path here, instead of "src". You can do this by editing the build path after the import process, of course.

Comment: @JonSkeet:How do I put Java as route? I can not see how to do that via the build path dialog. If I edit to place `src/java in Java Build Path->Source` i get the error "folder src\java" already exists

Comment: @user384706: You may need to remove "src" as a root first, but then under the "Source" tab you should be able to just click on "Add" and then browse to the right place. I don't have Eclipse in front of me right now, so I can't give exact details - but the Build Path dialog is the right place to tinker.

Comment: @Jon Skeet you're right. @user384706 you may want to create a source directory, say src1, and link source.

Comment: I removed src in the Source tab of build bath, and now created `java/java`. Worse is I remove the project, re-import it but eclipse does not see src\java from original project but sees java\java. How can this be fixed?

Comment: @user384706: What do you mean by "and now created java/java"? You shouldn't need to create any directories yourself at all. Under "Configure Build Path", click on the "Source" tab, then "Add folder..." That should let you browse to the *existing* src/java folder.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: On folder addition it says: Nesting of src/java is not allowed and remove java from src. If I remove the src from build path and add only src/java will this affect my filesystem?

Answer (score 5):

Remove the existing source folders first. -right click -> menu -> build path -> remove from build path

then

Right click on the source folder. build path -> use as source folder.

Seems like your settings are pointing to the parent of the source folder so src is recognized as package by eclipse.

[Wrong package name when using automatically added imports in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510605/wrong-package-name-when-using-automatically-added-imports-in-eclipse/4510947#4510947)

Comment: @fatih:"Seems like your settings are pointing to the parent of the source folder so src". How is these settings configured/changed?

Comment: Project properties -> Build Path - > Source tab    or like described in the message above

Comment: @fatih:These do not affect the filesystem of the project, right?

Comment: No, it is configuration for your IDE only. Does not change directory structure. (will add a new .settings folder to root which will keeps those settings inside)

Comment: @fatih:I see. The old .settings folder of the project I imported will be deleted?

Comment: no, it wont get deleted. Thats the place where eclipse keeps project specific settings. What it will do is, it is gonna update values inside of config files when you change sth. You should change those and compare with old ones to see what has changed.

Answer (score 0):

call the package on the top of your import statements,

like if your class is in java/main/org/goal/Main.java

then the path is package java.main.org.goal;

else do Ctrl +1 and it suggest some quick help

import the necessary package from that

Comment: not downvoting, but I think you're wrong. The Java project structure, specially Maven driven ones, have class path start from "/java/main". The app code goes under `main` and the classes start from there. So, `java.main.org.goal.*` is wrong, it should be `org.goal.*`

Answer (score 0):

Use this sentence `import java.io.*;` at the top of java file. Otherwise, you have to create package folder.

Import statements:

In Java if a fully qualified name, which includes the package and the class name, is given then the compiler can easily locate the source code or classes. Import statement is a way of giving the proper location for the compiler to find that particular class.

For example, the following line would ask compiler to load all the classes available in directory java_installation/java/io :

`import java.io.*`;